# Liquibase include with context

Tags: liquibase

I need to include files in a databaseChangeLog, but these files may not exist, depending on the installation.
My idea was to use something like includes with context, so Liquibase will only try to open the file when the appropriate context is given:

```
<include file=”myFile” context=”myContext”/>
```

But context is not used in an include tag, and Liquibase fails because the file is not present.
I’ll rather not use includeAll because I need the files to be included at specific parts of my main file.
Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Which version of liquibase are you using?

The "context" was added to the include tag in this [commit](https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase/commit/3c9e8be72e1f6a02a5195ca6951f52d8e575be60#diff-f7445281ccaf72040c6d51fd3eb6a51a).

Also check out this jira ticket: [CORE-155](https://liquibase.jira.com/browse/CORE-155).

So maybe your version of liquibase is just too old (below 3.5.0)?

Comment: Thanks! That’s what I need! But it fails if the file does not exist, regardless of the context I use. I think this is a bug.
I was using version 3.5.5, but now I’m using version 3.6.2 and the problem persists.

Comment: I guess it is not necessarily a bug. Liquibase will first parse your (xml) changelog files. And once that is done it will execute the collected changes. The `include` tag is evaluated in the phase of parsing the xml. And part of the parsing phase is evaluating the included files. The `context` is probably only used after the parsing when the changeset are run against the db.
Maybe having the `context` attribute on the `include` tag is just used to not execute all changes of the included file at once (instead of putting the `context` on each change). 
It's just my understanding of it...

Comment: Maybe [preconditions](https://www.liquibase.org/documentation/preconditions.html) can do what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks! I'll suggest to add the option to prevent failing when the file doesn't exist.

Answer (score 4):

Along with what Jens said, make sure you update your XML schema version. The one they have in the documentation (currently 3.1) doesn't not support this. Updating it to 3.5 works for me.

```
<databaseChangeLog
    xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.5.xsd">
```

(Note the 3.5 at the very end)