# Liquibase treat PostgreSQL schemas separately

Tags: maven, database-schema, database-migration, liquibase

Liquibase amazes me.

I need to treat evolving of two PostgreSQL schemas separately. That means keep changelogs per schema and not to mix its tables together obviously.

With this Maven settings I was able to generate initial change log per schema:

```
<configuration>
                    <propertyFileWillOverride>false</propertyFileWillOverride>
                    <propertyFile>src/main/resources/liquibase/${ctlg}/liquibase.${ctlg}.properties</propertyFile>
                    <driver>org.postgresql.Driver</driver>
                    <url>jdbc:postgresql://212.89.239.181:5432/vedica_dev?currentSchema=audit</url>
                    <username>user</username>
                    <password>pass</password>
                    <diffChangeLogFile>
                        src/main/resources/liquibase/${ctlg}/changelog/${maven.build.timestamp}_changelog.xml
                    </diffChangeLogFile>
                    <defaultSchemaName>
                        ${ctlg}
                    </defaultSchemaName>
                    <changeLogFile>
                        src/main/resources/liquibase/${ctlg}/main.xml</changeLogFile>
                    <outputChangeLogFile>
                        src/main/resources/liquibase/${ctlg}/${ctlg}_init.xml
                    </outputChangeLogFile>
                    <promptOnNonLocalDatabase>false</promptOnNonLocalDatabase>
                    <referenceUrl>
                        hibernate:spring:com.nws.vedica.model?dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL92Dialect
                    </referenceUrl>
</configuration>
```

change log file `main.xml`:

```
<databaseChangeLog
        xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog
         http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.1.xsd">

    <include file="src/main/resources/audit/audit_init.xml" />

</databaseChangeLog>
```

So, in configuration you see I needed to introduce maven profiles with ${ctlg} variable to be able to distinguish between public/audit settings folders. There is a properties file for each .prop file that states the `defaultSchemaName` that is being read properly (I can see from the log) I introduced it to the maven settings just to be sure.

And still when I do `mvn liquibase:diff -P audit` **it generates diff of the public and audit schema together.**

Like I hardly believe that and I might to overlook/set something but I'm being desperate here.

So the question is: how do I force liquibase (3.5.3) to treat PostgreSQL(9.6) schemas separately?

Please advice.

Comment: Maybe this will help somehow.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51179726/liquibase-include-with-context

Comment: that's something different there